# How to manipulate a Check box in Word with Java and save as PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, checkbox, ms-word, docx

I need to edit some Check-Boxes in a big Wordfile (docx) and save this then as PDF. This file contains many images and is about 19MB big.
Maybe there will be the need of adding some Checkbox and text.

My idea was to use docx4j, but before to learn the ropes I want to ask if this is possible and which is the best way.

May it be better to save the document as a PDF and then use this as base for processing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manipulate checkboxes using docx4j.

Be aware that there are several different kinds of checkboxes:

- legacy checkbox
- content control checkbox
- checkbox character

and the details depend on which type are present.

For more, you should post a snippet of the relevant OpenXML (and as they say here on SO, code showing what you've tried).

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use only docx4j?
Recently i tried a solution that helps me manage a Word document with checkboxes and save it as a PDF file. I used Plumsail Documents. The case is about how to populate a Word template using a form with checkboxes. You can connect your app via Zapier or Power Automate to activate checkboxes depending on value from your app. You can set the resulting file as a PDF and deliver it by email and across any system using Zapier and Power Automate.

The great is that Plumsail Documents has a templating engine that allows it to operate pictures.

Your case may be like this:

1. Create a form in Plumsail Form. It will allow you to activate checkboxes depending on your needs, or your users' needs.
2. Create a process in Plumsail Documents, upload your Word document and set it as a template. Just put placeholders where you want to change or fill a document with some values or data. Set the resulting document in PDF format.
3. Set the delivery method. Save across apps or deliver by email.

I recommend you to [read the article](https://plumsail.com/docs/documents/v1.x/flow/how-tos/documents/populate-word-with-checkbox.html). That solution is not free, but there is a free 30-day trial, so you will have enough time to try it.